# Running webserver and TCP server simultaneously

Tags: python, web, tcp, flask

I have a webserver setup using Flask, and it works. In addition, I have a demo TCP server, which also works. I want them to run in the same process, so they can communicate; however, I am running into difficulties, as they both want to open a port, and I get the error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

My understanding is that one process cannot open more than one port—but correct me if I'm mistaken. Is it possible to run subprocesses each with their own port? Or is there an easy way to communicate between processes in Python?

What's the best way to get a webserver and a TCP server to communicate information, such as updates to one reflecting in the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running your Flask app on the development web server in debug mode? Any difference if you run it with `debug=False`?

Answer (score 0):

use different port number for flask web server and TCP server.

Comment: I am: 5000 for Flask, 12321 for TCP.

Comment: you might be accidentally running same process twice while debugging, run this command ps -fA | grep python and kill the extra process

Comment: Nope. Nothing showed up, and restarting did not fix the issue either.

Comment: can you run lsof command and grep for TCP and see the status of port 5000 and 12321. if you don't see any port in the result then i strongly feel its script issue.

Comment: check for allow_reuse_address which can be set to True

Comment: Yep. I've added that pretty much everywhere I can.

Answer (score 0):

A process can use multiple ports, but you normally don't want multiple processes using the same port.

In this case, you probably just need a pair of SO_REUSEADDR's, one in each of your processes:
http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Normally, a *ix kernel will refuse to allow getting data from a port, even after the process that was using it exits - for a while.  This is seen as a security issue, because otherwise some other process could listen on the port afterward, and get data that was intended for the first process.  SO_REUSEADDR tells the kernel "Don't do that".